# Rails Undefined Method in an unknown way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model, undefined

I cloned a project that runs just fine. I did the `bundle install`, `bundle update`, `db:create`, `db:migrate`, and whatnot.

Now when I run `http://localhost:3000/orders/new` it returns a `NoMethodError in Admin::Orders#new`

I have this as part of my code under `model/admin/area.rb`

```
has_many :admin_accounts, :class_name => 'Admin::Account'

validates :name, :presence => true
validates :timezone, :presence => true
validates :time_offset, :presence => true
validates :shift_time1, :presence => true
validates :shift_time2, :presence => true
validates :unit_price_12, :presence => true
validates :unit_price_24, :presence => true

def next_shift_time_from_now
  current_time = Time.zone.now
  next_shift_time(current_time)
end

def next_shift_time(time)
  shift1 = time.change(hour: self[:shift_time1].hour)
  shift2 = time.change(hour: self[:shift_time2].hour)
  get_shift(time, shift1, shift2)
end
```

And this under my `accounts.rb`

```
require 'digest/md5'
before_save :encrypt_password
after_initialize :default_values

has_many :admin_orders, :class_name => 'Admin::Order'
belongs_to :admin_areas, :class_name => 'Admin::Area', :foreign_key => 'area_id'
```

under `new.html`

```
<div class="page-header clearfix">
  <div class="pull-right"><%= link_to 'Back', orders_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %></div>
  <h3 class="pull-left">
    Creating New Order
  </h3>
</div>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

and this under `_form.html.erb` which has the error

```
    <div class="form-group field-bottom-container">
      <label id="nextShiftTime">Next Shift Time</label>

      <div>
        <% @user = Admin::Account.find($user_id) %>
        <%= @nextShiftTime=format_datetime(@user.admin_areas.next_shift_time_from_now) %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The error is this line: `<%= @nextShiftTime=format_datetime(@user.admin_areas.next_shift_time_from_now) %>`

which returns...
***undefined method `next_shift_time_from_now' for nil:NilClass***

Is there anything I must configure to fix this? I think there's nothing wrong with the code since it worked well previously and upon recent clone, with no changes with the codes i might add, the program is causing this error.

Comment: Since @user.admin_areas is nil, can you post the user model?

Comment: i have no user model. the models used are account and area. the admin_areas belongs to area.rb as well as the def next_shift_time_from_now @jphager2
the 'at' user gets the account model by the way

Comment: Ok got it. So first thing: belongs_to :admin_areas is plural. Is that intentional? Because you are only expecting one admin_area. Secondly, did you assign an area_id to the account in the database? I'm guessing `@user.area_id == nil`

Comment: The line `<% @user = Admin::Account.find($user_id) %>` violates at least three Rails' best practice pattern.

Comment: @jphager2 i just found out that area_id turned null in my database. thanks a lot!! that solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line

```
@nextShiftTime=format_datetime(@user.admin_areas.next_shift_time_from_now)
```

returns an `undefined method 'next_shift_time_from_now' for nil:NilClass` error, then the only possible explanation is that `@user.admin_areas` returns `nil`.

Look into your database: You have at least one `Admin::Account` without a matching `Admin::Area`.

Comment: what data should I add? the other clone of this same project went well with same codes... don't the versions of ruby/rails matter or what?

Comment: thanks... it helped me trace the problem. i just found out that my area_id is null in my database